# Writing to SD card

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am writing some files to SD card. My android version is 2.1. I am not setting any  permission in the manifest file but it allows me to write to sd card.

Please let me know why this behavior. only WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in manifest controls write to SD card or any other configuration i need to do.

thanks
Gururaja B O

Answer (score 2):

Are you compiling with API level 3 or less? That permission was added in API level 4 (Android 1.6), so all apps compiled with API level 3 (for compatibility with phones still running 1.5) will have that permission automatically.

Comment: I am using Eclair code base to build the system images, which is having API level greater than 3. Whether I need to modify any other configuration apart from checking API level?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a utils method to check a SD card is available on device or not, and get SD card path on device if it available.

You can copy 2 methods bellow into your project's class that you need. Create your project's folder on the path returned and write data on it. That's all.

```
public String isRemovableSDCardAvailable() {
    final String FLAG = "mnt";
    final String SECONDARY_STORAGE = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");
    final String EXTERNAL_STORAGE_DOCOMO = System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE_DOCOMO");
    final String EXTERNAL_SDCARD_STORAGE = System.getenv("EXTERNAL_SDCARD_STORAGE");
    final String EXTERNAL_SD_STORAGE = System.getenv("EXTERNAL_SD_STORAGE");
    final String EXTERNAL_STORAGE = System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE");

    Map<Integer, String> listEnvironmentVariableStoreSDCardRootDirectory = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    listEnvironmentVariableStoreSDCardRootDirectory.put(0, SECONDARY_STORAGE);
    listEnvironmentVariableStoreSDCardRootDirectory.put(1, EXTERNAL_STORAGE_DOCOMO);
    listEnvironmentVariableStoreSDCardRootDirectory.put(2, EXTERNAL_SDCARD_STORAGE);
    listEnvironmentVariableStoreSDCardRootDirectory.put(3, EXTERNAL_SD_STORAGE);
    listEnvironmentVariableStoreSDCardRootDirectory.put(4, EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    File externalStorageList[] = null;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        externalStorageList = getContext().getExternalFilesDirs(null);
    }
    String directory = null;
    int size = listEnvironmentVariableStoreSDCardRootDirectory.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (externalStorageList != null && externalStorageList.length > 1 && externalStorageList[1] != null)
            directory = externalStorageList[1].getAbsolutePath();
        else
            directory = listEnvironmentVariableStoreSDCardRootDirectory.get(i);

        directory = canCreateFile(directory);
        if (directory != null && directory.length() != 0) {
            if (i == size - 1) {
                if (directory.contains(FLAG)) {
                    Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "SD Card's directory: " + directory);
                    return directory;
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "SD Card's directory: " + directory);
            return directory;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * Check if can create file on given directory. Use this enclose with method
 * {@link BeginScreenFragement#isRemovableSDCardAvailable()} to check sd
 * card is available on device or not.
 * 
 * @param directory
 * @return
 */
public String canCreateFile(String directory) {
    final String FILE_DIR = directory + File.separator + "hoang.txt";
    File tempFlie = null;
    try {
        tempFlie = new File(FILE_DIR);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFlie);
        fos.write(new byte[1024]);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Can write file on this directory: " + FILE_DIR);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Write file error: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } finally {
        if (tempFlie != null && tempFlie.exists() && tempFlie.isFile()) {
            // tempFlie.delete();
            tempFlie = null;
        }
    }
    return directory;
}
```